# Can I user counter type field as primary key of my C* table?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

When I am trying to create table like below

```
 create table if not exists counter_temp(id counter PRIMARY KEY , comment text);
```

It is giving error as below

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - For a table with counter columns, all columns except the primary    key must be type counter
> - counter type is not supported for PRIMARY KEY part

**Question 1 :**

What is the reason , counter column not allowed as part of primary key?

**Question 2 :**
While I am trying to create as below

create table if not exists counter_temp(id uuid PRIMARY KEY, counter_t counter, comment text)

> Error : Cant mix counter and non-counter columns in the same table
>
> What is wrong here ? how to handle it correct way ?

**Question 3 :**

I have a table emp( emp_id counter, emp_name text)  in Dev env where has data , now I need to copy that data into another SIT env  emp( emp_id counter, emp_name text) table ?

Can it be done  will it copy counter fields properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer for question 1 is **No**, as it was communicated in the error message. But Even if it was allowed, then it didn't make any sense - when you change value of the primary key, you're basically create a new row with different primary key.

for Q2 - if there is at least one `counter` column in the table, then all other regular columns should have type `counter`. If you need to add a comment field, just create a 2nd table, with `UUID` primary key & insert or read data to/from 2 tables at the same time.

for Q3 - cqlsh's `COPY` command supports tables with counters for newer Cassandra versions (where fix for [CASSANDRA-9043](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9043) is implemented).  Also, Spark Cassandra Connector is able to read from tables with counters & write to them. But in both cases make sure that the target table is empty, otherwise new values will be appended to existing ones.

Comment: for Q2 you can have only a table with counters as non-primary key columns (regular columns). You can't mix columns of counter type with other column types. In this case, just add a separate table for your `comment` column, like this `(id uuid PRIMARY KEY, comment text)`, and write to it separately